# How to list/kill running commands in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to run a COPY command on my Cassandra cluster (v3.0.9).
In case my shell exits, how can I later on list running commands, get their status and possibly kill/stop it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a cql file with your COPY command
2. Run it through cqlsh using -f flag (cqlsh -f ) with nohup. Details [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm).

Then it will be available to ps and kill.

Comment: when shell exits, for example on disconnect, then commands running in background will be killed as their parent will be killed...